# In how many ways, can 16 people be seated at 4 different circular tables(4 seats for each table), asuming all seats are taken.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Since the question explicitly says that all seats should be taken, and since those are circular tables I also made the assumption that orientations clockwise and anticlockwise are different, thus $(n-1)!$.

I ended up with the following solution:

$1^\circ$ Table : $\frac{15!}{4!}$

$2^\circ$ Table : $\frac{11!}{4!}$

$3^\circ$ Table : $\frac{7!}{4!}$

$4^\circ$ Table : $3!$

Number of possible combinations $ = \frac{15!}{4!} + \frac{11!}{4!} + \frac{7!}{4!} + 3! $

Would this be the correct way of solving the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, each partition of the $16$ people into groups of $4$ represents a different seating.  The number of such partitions is

$$P = \binom{16}{4} \times \binom{12}{4} \times \binom{8}{4} = \frac{(16!)}{(4!)^4}.$$

Note that the above computation accommodates that the $(4)$ tables are to be considered **distinguishable** from each other.  If that were not the case, then you would have to add the factor of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(4!)}$ to represent that each partitioning would otherwise be **overcounted**  $(4!)$ times.

Then, for each such partition, since a specific table is **round**, you can arbitrarily assign one person at the head of the table, and then reason that the remaining $(3)$ people can be seated in $(3!)$ different ways around the table.

Therefore, the final computation is

$$P \times (3!)^4 = \frac{(16!)}{(4!)^4} \times (3!)^4 = \frac{(16!)}{(4)^4}.$$